# Symfony local server start

Tags: php, symfony

I have a very weird error with symfony. If I create a project with the default project creation command and go into the new folder to start the local webserver I get an error:

```
Jan 27 17:51:00 |DEBUG| PHP    Reloading PHP versions 
Jan 27 17:51:00 |DEBUG| PHP    Using PHP version 7.4.2 (from default version in $PATH) 
Jan 27 17:51:00 |DEBUG| PHP    unable to find an available port error="lookup localhost on AN_INTERESTING_IP: no such host" path="/usr/bin/php" php="7.4.2"
Jan 27 17:51:00 |INFO | SERVER shut down, bye! 

  lookup localhost on AN_INTERESTING_IP: no such host
```

Yesterday I had no problems to start the local webserver.
Additionally, the interesting thing is, if I start the local webserver in an other non-symfony-directory the webserver starts without an exception.

Maybe someone has experience with this problem?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem today and for some reason the file /etc/hosts lacked an entry for localhost. So I added

`127.0.0.1 localhost`

After that it worked just fine.

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution! I don't know why this happend...